# Number(string) sometimes returns NaN for valid negative float string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have string `"-11.5"` inside React state. Sometimes when passing this string to either `Number(state)` or `parseFloat(state)` I get `NaN`.

This doesn't occur when passing string literal or const variable instead of state to either of these functions.

Example:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState("-11.5");
const c = "-11.5";

console.log(state, Number(state), parseFloat(state)); // -> -11.5 NaN NaN
console.log("-11.5", Number("-11.5"), parseFloat("-11.5")); // -> -11.5 -11.5 -11.5
console.log(c, Number(c), parseFloat(c)); // -> -11.5 -11.5 -11.5
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: add a `console.log(typeof state)`. In the initial version of your question you had a typo which would explain this behavior (ie `state` being a number not a string)

Comment: Check that the `state` really is "-11.5" by also logging it `console.log(state === "-11.5")`. If this is isn't true then check every single character. For example, it might be that the hyphen is not the usual hyphen but a U+2212 code point. Many other things could be wrong with that string, just compare.

Comment: @trincot that was it! toLocaleString included U+2212.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `useState` is asynchronous. If you immediately try to use that state you might not get the expected value.

Consider using `useEffect`, it runs after any state changes and it will always log the correct value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state, Number(state), parseFloat(state));
}, [state]);
```

Comment: Sorry, typo was in question only - I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it's kinda embarassing:

I constructed string in state using `toLocaleString`:

```js
const num = -11.5;
const str = num.toLocaleString("sl-SI");
```

At this point `str` is `"−11,5"`. Note that `−` (U+2212) is not `-` (U+002D), even though they are visually exactly the same.

Then I converted it naively into decimal string:

```js
const dec = str.replaceAll(",", ".");

// So we have now dec = "−11.5" where "−" is U+2212
parseFloat(dec); // NaN
```

So problem occurs due to `toLocaleString` with `sl-SI` locale using U+2212 instead of U+002D minus sign, which parsers don't understand. Fix is relatively simple `dec.replaceAll("−", "-")`.

Comment: And that's, why it's important to show the actual code in the question and not replace things with values you think they'll have ...

Comment: @derpirscher I admit, I made a mess when trying to create minimal example. Actual code goes through a lot of other hoops, and I really didn't think that problem will occur in toLocalestring step. Sorry.